# Limiting input string characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, strlen

I am trying to write a simple code where the user has to enter a string,but if the string has more than five characters it should print out an error and return -1.
I used fgets to get the input and strlen to calculate the length of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
  {
    char a[5];
    int length = 0;

    printf("Enter a string to calculate it's length\n");
    fgets(a,5,stdin);

    length = strlen(a)-1; // don't want the '\n' to be counted

    if(length > 5){

        printf("error");
    }
    printf("string length %d\n",length);


       return 0;
 }
```

When i enter a string with more than 5 characters it doesn't print out the error , it just prints out that the string size is three.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For one thing you'll need a bigger buffer.

Comment: Please read e.g. [this `fgets` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), and learn what the second argument to it means.

Comment: Never use a tiny buffer size like 5.  If the user tries to enter a 20-character string, how will you read it so that you can call `strlen` on it and discover that its length is too long?

Comment: If you only read 5 characters, how do you expect to know if there are more waiting to be read? Get a larger buffer, read a few extra characters, then check if what you read is larger than it should be.

Comment: thank you all i made a silly mistake.  @Someprogrammerdude the second argument was crucial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fgets(a,5,stdin);
```

`fgets` always reads size-1 charecters.

Reading  stops  after  an
       EOF  or a newline.
So, it reads only 4 charecters.

```
length = strlen(a)-1;   // 4-1 = 3
```

Comment: "fgets always reads size-1 charecters" - not if it encounters end of line or EOF first. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `strchr` to check for a newline. If there is no newline in the input, read characters until a newline is found to clear the input buffer and retry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char a[7];//five characters, a newline and a zero terminator
    int toolong = 0;

    do {
        if ( toolong) {
            printf ( "too many characters. try again\n");
        }
        toolong = 0;
        printf ( "enter up to five characters.\n");
        if ( fgets ( a, sizeof a, stdin)) {
            while ( ! strchr ( a, '\n')) {//check for newline
                toolong = 1;
                fgets ( a, sizeof a, stdin);//read more characters
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( toolong);

    return 0;
}
```